# Error - Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'-

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon. I am developing an augmented reality experience. I'm creating a function where touching a button executes a createElement and creates an entity(3d model). Until then, everything is fine. Then I am developing another functionality so that when the createElement of one of the buttons is executed, the child of the other is deleted, in case it is rendered.

[image]

The idea is that when you click on RED BSC, the 2 buttons that derive from touching RED ETH20 are removed, but instead I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

data.js

```js
export const data = [
  {
    net: 'eth',
    model1: {
      id: 'eth-1',
      position: {x: 14, y: 5, z: 0},
      scale: {x: 1.5, y: 1.5, z: 1.5},
      model: 'asset-mana',
    },
    model2: {
      id: 'eth-2',
      position: {x: 14, y: 3, z: 0},
      scale: {x: 1.5, y: 1.5, z: 1.5},
      model: 'asset-sand',
    },
  },
  {
    net: 'bsc',
    model1: {
      id: 'bsc-1',
      position: {x: 14, y: 2, z: 0},
      scale: {x: 1.5, y: 1.5, z: 1.5},
      model: 'asset-cake',
    },
  },
]
```

utils.js

```js
const removeInfoModels = () => {
    const infoModel1 = document.getElementById('eth-1')
    const infoModel2 = document.getElementById('eth-2')
    const infoModel3 = document.getElementById('bsc-1')
    if (infoModel3) {
      wrapper.removeChild(infoModel1)
      wrapper.removeChild(infoModel2)
    } else if (infoModel1) {
       wrapper.removeChild(infoModel3)
    }
  }


  const createEntity2 = (id, scale, position, model) => {
    // creamos la entidad
    const entity = document.createElement('a-entity')
    entity.setAttribute('id', id)
    entity.setAttribute('scale', scale)
    entity.setAttribute('position', position)
    entity.setAttribute('gltf-model', `#${model}`)

    // la metemos al html
    wrapper.appendChild(entity)
  }

  const showInfoModels = (data, netType) => {
    removeInfoModels()
    const dataObj = data.filter(obj => obj.net === netType)

    const question = dataObj.filter(element => element.model2)  // = true

    if (question) {
      dataObj.forEach((elemento) => {
        createEntity2(dataObj[0].model1.id, dataObj[0].model1.scale, dataObj[0].model1.position, dataObj[0].model1.model)
        createEntity2(dataObj[0].model2.id, dataObj[0].model2.scale, dataObj[0].model2.position, dataObj[0].model2.model)
      })
    } else {
      dataObj.forEach((elemento) => {
        createEntity2(dataObj[0].model1.id, dataObj[0].model1.scale, dataObj[0].model1.position, dataObj[0].model1.model)
      })
    }

  }
```

Comment: One of the elements you try to get isn't in the dom and returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

So just based on your provided code, I do not see where the `wrapper` variable is declared.

Regardless, you may want to just directly remove the elements with `.remove()` instead of trying to remove them from the parent with `.removeChild()`.

So essentially you would have something like:

```
infoModel1.remove();
```

Calling `.remove()` directly on the element you wish to remove often times is easier than trying to remove it from the parent.